# Oracle connection problems on Windows

Tags: windows, oracle, connection

I have Oracle 11g RDBMS and 11g Forms and Reports installed on my Windows Vista PC.

No environment variables are set for `ORACLE_SID`, `ORACLE_HOME` or `TNS_ADMIN`

Registry settings in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\` :

```
#Database
ORACLE_HOME = E:\app\Tams\product\11.1.0\db_1
ORACLE_SID = orcl
#Forms and Reports
ORACLE_HOME = C:\bimwh\Oracle_FRHome1
TNS_ADMIN = E:\app\Tams\product\11.1.0\db_1\NETWORK\ADMIN

#tnsnames.ora
tams=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Tams-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

#sqlnet.ora
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

#listener.ora
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Tams-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

#tnsping
C:\>tnsping tams

Used parameter files:
E:\app\Tams\product\11.1.0\db_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Tams-PC)
(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))
OK (0 msec)

#sqlplus
C:\>sqlplus user/pass@tams  - HANGS.
C:\>sqlplus user/pass@orcl  - ORA-12154.
C:\>sqlplus user/pass       - CONNECTS.

#Forms and Reports Builder
user/pass/tams - ORA-12154 on Reports - HANGS on Forms.
user/pass/orcl - ORA-12154 on both.
user/pass      - CONNECTS.

#Forms Runtime
ORA-12560 TNS protocol adapter error
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.
Tams

Comment: Did you follow the installation guide and install a loopback adapter before installing the database?  If so, what IP address did you assign to that adapter?  Does "Tams-PC" resolve to that IP address (i.e. in the `hosts` file)?

Comment: I installed the database about three years ago. I don't remember any loopback adapter. If I did, then I don't recall the IP addrsss I assigned to it. Where would I find it? Tams-PC resolves to 10.10.10.10 in hosts file.

Comment: It was set to 10.10.10.10 a week ago when I installed Repository Utility Creation.

Comment: @Tams:Please find a link to install and configure microsoft loopback adapter [link](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004779)

Comment: @Tams - Did this work a week ago before you installed ` Repository Utility Creation` (is that an Oracle Forms thing?)

Comment: @Gaurav, I've carried out those instructions and rebooted my machine, but it hasn't made any difference. I believe I also did the same thing last week when I installed RCU which was a prerequisite for Business Intelligence. Justin, I don't know if last week changed anything because prior to then I just connected to my database without naming the database.

Comment: If you haven't already fixed or abandoned this issue, I would recommend that you try calling SQLPLUS using the full path to the copy in the Database Home (C:\app\Tams\product\11.1.0\db_1\bin\sqlplus.exe) and the one in the Middleware Home (C:\bimwh\Oracle_FRHome1\bin\sqlplus.exe) and report on the results. Do the same with TNSPING. Also, if you could share the contents of your PATH environment variable, that would also be helpful in determining which of these instances of SQLPLUS and TNSPING are being called.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the listener is not listening for any databases. The only entry in the listener.ora is the listener definition itself. Normally there is also a list of databases the listener is listening for. The Network Manager can be used to configure the listener to listen for the local databases. Once the listener.ora is listening for the databases the connect user/pass@net-service-name should work.